# What he did is... - can this simply tell us "somebody did something"?

Tags: meaning, tense

In my view, when we talk about someone doing something in the past, we often use "what he did **was**...", "what he ate **was**...", etc.

I think most of the time it should be used with past tense.

But I think it can be used with present tense, too when it means "is considered to be."

For example,

**Example 1**

> What he did was killing animals.

Simply tells us that he killed animals.

> What he did is killing animals.

"Now, the thing he did is considered to be killing animals "

A possible context:

> What he did was killing animals. However, by modern standards, actually what he did is preserving nature.

**Example 2**

> What he ate was cold noodles.

> What he ate is ramen.

"Now, the thing he ate is considered to be ramen."

A possible context:

> What he ate was cold noodles. However, by modern standards, What he ate is ramen.

**Questions**

Is my understanding about "what he did was..." and "what he did is..." correct?

Is "what he did was..." more correct?

or

"what he did is..." can also simply tell us the fact that somebody does something?

Comment: Couldn't you say kills bugs or insects? It is terrible to have to reread that sentence and to reproduce it.

Comment: This is a construction called a _wh_-cleft. The tense of the _be_ is irrelevant, since it's a dummy inserted by the clefting rule and has no meaning. English little words like _be, of, the, at,_ are just pieces of the grammar and don't mean anything. So their tense, number, person, and gender just don't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I disagree. I understand, however, your objective.

> What he did was killing animals

is a clunky but grammatical way to say

> He killed animals

or

> What he did was to kill animals

I am not saying that you can never have a past and present combined

> What he did is still killing animals

is perfectly grammatical. And that is how most people will interpret

> What he did is killing animals.

They will view that sentence as describing a past act with current consequences.

So I am **NOT** saying that we have a grammatical rule against having past and present in the same sentence. I am talking about meaning, both intended and received.

> What he did is the killing of animals

is a way, grammatical but in my opinion obscure, to convey

> What he did is now considered to be the killing of animals.

My point is that when a participle is used as a gerund, that is a noun as indicated by the article “the,” no time aspect is involved. Nouns do not have tense. But your meaning that current views consider what he did to be the killing of animals (with the implication that views at the time of the killing were different) is lost by the use of the gerund alone.

The purpose of language is to convey meaning. That requires more than being grammatical.

**EDIT**: This edit relates to the original poster’s comment to my original answer.

In general, if you want to be clear about changing meanings, you seldom do it through tense or other grammatical devices **ALONE**. People will almost always understand what you speak or write by the meanings current when heard or read unless you explicitly make clear that you are talking about a difference in meaning.

You can use purely grammatical means as a rhetorical device.

> What graft is is not what graft was.

That is grammatical but obscure on its own. It is fine, however, as an introductory sentence.

> What graft is is not what graft was. Boss Croker obviously had neither ethical nor legal reservations about what he called “honest graft.” Legal and ethical standards have changed since the late 19th century. Little if any of his “honest graft” would be deemed ethical in North America in the 21st century, and some would be outright illegal.

English is a subtle language, but complicated ideas about changing mores are not best expressed by tinkering with tenses.

Comment: Thank you. Now I understand the confusion caused by my "What he did is killing animals." If I rewrite it as "What he did is to kill animals," will it mean "Now, from a modern point of view or for a modern average human, the thing he did is an act of killing animals"?

Comment: @vincentlin See edit.

Answer (score 1):

OP's first example...

> 1: *What he did was killing animals*

...is already *slightly* "unusual" phrasing compared to the more common version...

> 1a: *What he did was [to] kill animals*

Including the optional "infinitive marker" ***to*** in (1a) is normally just a stylistic choice with no effect on meaning. But it *can* be included specifically to force the interpretation the the animals died *later*, as a (probably unintended) consequence of something he did earlier.

In this context, it's worth noting that whether to repeat the initial Past Tense in such contexts, OR switch to Present Tense often has little or no effect on meaning. For example...

> 2a: *What he said was outrageous*
> 2b: *What he said is outrageous*

...where arguably (2b) carries a stronger sense of "immediacy" (speaker is *currently* outraged). But it's really just a stylistic choice.

Note that example #1 here features ***redefinition*** (killing animals ***is*** the thing that he did), whereas my example #2 simply assigns an ***adjectival description*** to his (past) action. But that past action can *still* be redefined / described in the same way at time of speaking, so both Present and Past work perfectly well in both those contexts.

---

OP's "alternative interpretation" of Present Tense in his first example *(By today's standards, the thing he did in the past is now considered to be "killing animals")* is a bit fanciful. Because the *continuous / gerund* verb form *(killing)* is already slightly unusual, native speakers will often cast about for some "slightly unusual *meaning*" to assign to the text. But in and of themselves, the words don't *actually* carry that meaning in any real sense.

Comment: Thank you. Does the same concept also apply to the ramen example? What he ate was ramen -> redefinition in the past; What he ate is ramen -> redefinition in the present.

Comment: As @Jeff points out, *What he ate is/was ramen* is "unusual" phrasing compared to plain *He ate ramen*. You should avoid thinking that the unusual version (with Present / Past for the "copula" verb ***is/was***) has *any* particular meaning. It's just unusual phrasing, so native speakers would assume *some* kind of unusual meaning where the exact context should help us guess why the speaker chose those words (unless it came from a non-native speaker, in which case we'd probably just ignore the "quirkiness").

Comment: ...crucial here is @JohnLawler's comment *(the tense of the **be** is irrelevant, since it's a dummy inserted by the clefting rule and has no meaning)*. Your attempt to impose some significance to the ***is/was** ramen* choice is largely pointless - if the name or classification of the substance had changed ***since*** he ate it, we'd simply use more words to clearly convey that point.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the construction "What [someone] did was" is generally used in conversation to introduce a further clause which explains what that person actually did. For example, "He was hungry, so what he did was, he killed some animals and ate them." Note that you could completely omit "what he did was" and no meaning would be lost. The only function of these words is to add some introductory drama, or perhaps to stall.

The interesting thing is that there are several alternative constructions for this, all of which find support in Google searches. Here's a list (and I'll switch to the pronoun "I," because I think this type of speaking is more common in stories that you tell about yourself, but theoretically it should apply to other pronouns as well):

> I was hungry, so what I did was, I killed some animals...
> I was hungry, so what I did was, is I killed some animals...
> I was hungry, so what I did was, was I killed some animals...
> I was hungry, so what I did was to kill some animals...
> I was hungry, so what I did was, was to kill some animals...
> I was hungry, so what I did is, I killed some animals...
> I was hungry, so what I did is, is I killed some animals...
> I was hungry, so what I did is to kill some animals...

I don't think the missing permutations involving "is, was" right after another are as common.

In any case, these sound informal and would be most common in fast, spoken language. None of them sound "wrong" to me or would stand out as remarkable or even noticeable if I heard them.

So, that's the main usage. What you've focused on in your question - how something is considered - is less common. You might be able to use this turn of phrase to express how something is considered *by you right now*, in which case the most common way to phrase it would probably be:

> What he did was to preserve nature.

But it's probably better to more clearly state the point, e.g.: "I consider what he did to be preserving nature."

As far as expressing how something used to be considered by society in the past, I think you also have to be explicit there to avoid confusion: "What he did was considered back then to be preserving nature."

Comment: ”What I did was/is I killed some animals“ Are both "was" and "is" mean the simple fact I killed some animals? Are there subtle differences? And thank you for the example sentences. What does it mean when you put two be-verbs together like the one in "I was hungry, so what I did is, is I killed some animals..."?

Comment: Yes, exactly, they are all past tense and express the bare fact that I killed some animals. I think they all mean the same thing, no subtle differences that I can discern, which is to say, they are all basically meaningless extra words. The double-be verbs just make it slightly longer without changing anything.